# random "munmap_chunk()" and segmentation fault errors

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have an issue that appears to be somewhat random. When I run the following code, sometimes it runs through till the finish, and sometimes it gives me errors like the following:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./Alg: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000eba0c0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7eb96)[0x7ff38230ab96]
./Alg[0x40084a]
./Alg[0x400bae]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7ff3822ad76d]
./Alg[0x4005e9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 00:16 1078                               /home/Students/jb2100/Desktop/Alg
00601000-00602000 r--p 00001000 00:16 1078                               /home/Students/jb2100/Desktop/Alg
00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 00:16 1078                               /home/Students/jb2100/Desktop/Alg
00eba000-00edb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7ff382076000-7ff38208b000 r-xp 00000000 2b:00 22376                      /rofs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ff38208b000-7ff38228a000 ---p 00015000 2b:00 22376                      /rofs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ff38228a000-7ff38228b000 r--p 00014000 2b:00 22376                      /rofs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ff38228b000-7ff38228c000 rw-p 00015000 2b:00 22376                      /rofs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ff38228c000-7ff382441000 r-xp 00000000 2b:00 22378                      /rofs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ff382441000-7ff382640000 ---p 001b5000 2b:00 22378                      /rofs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ff382640000-7ff382644000 r--p 001b4000 2b:00 22378                      /rofs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ff382644000-7ff382646000 rw-p 001b8000 2b:00 22378                      /rofs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ff382646000-7ff38264b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff38264b000-7ff38266d000 r-xp 00000000 2b:00 22391                      /rofs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.soAborted (core dumped)
```

I'm really not sure what is going on, and why sometimes it works and sometimes it doesnt. If you guys could provide some insight I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!
Below is my Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 40
#define BUFSIZE 10

struct queueNode
{
    int data;
    struct queueNode *next;

};

struct queue
{
    struct queueNode *first; //pointer to first item
    struct queueNode *last;  //pointer to last item


};

float calcBaseline(struct queue *q)
{
    printf("Starting baseline calc\n");
    struct queueNode *temp = q->first;
    float base = 0;
    int i, total = 0;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        total += temp->data;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    base = total/BUFSIZE;
    printf("ending baseline calc\n");
    return base;
}

void enqueue(struct queue *q, int value)
{
    printf("Starting enqueue\n");
    struct queueNode *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct queueNode));
    newNode->data = value;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if(q->first == NULL)//if queue is empty
    {
        q->first = q->last=newNode; //both first and last point to the new node
    }
    else
    {
        q->last->next = newNode; //append newNode after last element
        q->last = q->last->next; //point "last" pointer to the new node
    }
    printf("ending enqueue\n");
}

void dequeue(struct queue *q)
{
    printf("Starting dequeue\n");
    struct queueNode *temp = q->first;
    q->first = q->first->next; //moves first pointer to next item
    free(temp); //deletes the old first node
    printf("Ending dequeue\n");

}

void destroyQueue(struct queue *q)
{
    printf("Starting destroyQueue\n");
    struct queueNode *temp1 = q->first;
    struct queueNode *temp = q->first->next;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        free(temp1);
        temp1 = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("ending destroyQueue\n");

}

int main()
{

    int temp, i, j, TEST = 10;
    float baseline = 0.0;
    int *myArray;
    myArray = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));
    myArray[0] = 0;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    struct queue q;
    q.first = NULL;

    //initialize the queue
    for(i = 0; i < BUFSIZE; i++)
    {
        myArray[i] = rand()%TEST;
        enqueue(&q, myArray[i]);
    }
    baseline = calcBaseline(&q);
    printf("%.2f\n",baseline);

    //After baseline is established generate spikes and baseline numbers
    for (i = BUFSIZE; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        temp = rand()%100;
        if(temp <= 90)
        {
            myArray[i] = rand()%TEST;
            dequeue(&q);
            enqueue(&q, myArray[i]);
            baseline = calcBaseline(&q);
            printf("%.2f\n",baseline);
        }
        else
        {
            //Assume minimum spike rise time is 10 samples
            for(j = i; j < i+10; j++)
            {
                myArray[j] = myArray[j-1]+1;
                if(myArray[j] <TEST)
                {
                    dequeue(&q);
                    enqueue(&q, myArray[j]);
                    baseline = calcBaseline(&q);
                    printf("%.2f\n",baseline);
                }

            }
            for(j = i+10; j < i+20; j++)
            {
                myArray[j] = myArray[j-1]-1;
                if(myArray[j] <TEST)
                {
                    dequeue(&q);
                    enqueue(&q, myArray[j]);
                    baseline = calcBaseline(&q);
                    printf("%.2f\n",baseline);
                }
            }
            i+=19;
        }
        if(temp < 99)
        {
            TEST++;
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("myArray[%d] = %d\n",i, myArray[i]);
    }
    destroyQueue(&q);


return 0;

}
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to write a simpler example to isolate the problem. It might also help us to have a smaller example

Comment: Exactly; please do write a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: one thing I noticed `destroyQueue` may perform a free even with an empty queue. That could corrupt your heap.

Comment: Any output before the error message?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't free the following lines:

```
myArray = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));
```

and

```
struct queueNode *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct queueNode));
```

respectively line 111 and line 42.
But your main problem is in your function dequeue, you should have:

```
void dequeue(struct queue *q)
{
    printf("Starting dequeue\n");
    struct queueNode *temp = q->first->next;
    free(q->first); //deletes the old first node                                                                                                                                                             
    q->first = temp; //moves first pointer to next item                                                                                                                                                      
    printf("Ending dequeue\n");
}
```

instead of

```
void dequeue(struct queue *q)
{
    printf("Starting dequeue\n");
    struct queueNode *temp = q->first;
    q->first = q->first->next; //moves first pointer to next item
    free(temp); //deletes the old first node
    printf("Ending dequeue\n");

}
```

Because if you say temp = q->first and then q->first = q->first->next, there is chances that you might free q->first->next instead of q->first. By changing the order, you asure yourself that you indeed free the old pointer.